# How do I redirect to a specific route inside a controller method in Masonite framework?

Tags: python, masonite

In Masonite framework , How do I  redirect to a specific route  inside a controller method   ?

In update method (UnitController@update)  of my controller class UnitController  , I want to redirect the route to 'unit/@id' and  which eventually goes to UnitController@show method.

Note : In laravel , I do this by " return redirect('/units/'.$unit->id) " Statement.But I don't know how to do this in masonite framework.

Comment: Hello, did you ever figure this out?