# How do I redirect to an external route inside a controller method in Masonite framework?

Tags: masonite

In Masonite framework , How do I redirect to an external route inside a controller method?

I have tried the following, only for it to get stuck on "redirecting"

[image]

```
from masonite.views import View
from masonite.controllers import Controller
from masonite.request import Request
from masonite.response import Response


class SubmissionController(Controller):
    def show(self, request: Request, response: Response):
        response.header('Cache-Control', "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate")
        response.status(307)
        return response.redirect(f'http://msn.com')
```

This is similar to this question:
[How do I redirect to a specific route inside a controller method in Masonite framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76300134/635160)

Comment: Hello, I confirm this is a bug, follow this issue here: https://github.com/MasoniteFramework/masonite/issues/768